# Mock method with parameters

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to mock the below line but it gives an error while executing it, it says:

> Misplaced argument matcher detected here:
>
> You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
>
> Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
>
> when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
>
> doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
>
> verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
>
> Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with
>   methods that cannot be mocked. Following methods *cannot* be
>   stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
>
> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
>   The line of code is:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(NameOfClass.class);
expect( NameOfClass.nameOfMethod((URL)Mockito.any(),Mockito.anyString())).andReturn(actualOutput);
```

the class is somewhat like this:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static String method(String URL, String str) {
    //functioning
        return "";
    }
}
```

**How can I mock it?**

Comment: While Powermock(-ito) solves your actual problem you rather should not use `static` methods. They make your code inflexible and hard to reuse. You problem to mock them for test is a symptom of that design flaw.

Comment: i can't change things in my code.....it's an old code and getting used at many places

Comment: Are all this "many places" in your own application?

Comment: Have you added @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) runner to your class? Also try to annotate the test class with
@PrepareForTest(SomeClass.class)

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerMockito on top of Mockito. Something like this:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(NameOfClass.class);
expect( NameOfClass.nameOfMethod((URL)Mockito.any(),Mockito.anyString())).andReturn(actualOutput);
```

Comment: @TimothyTruckle sorry have overseen this Detail.

Comment: The Detail that mockito can not mock static methods should be a part of the answer, to explain why OP should use an other framework

Comment: @Jens - sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

> i can't change things in my code.....it's an old code and getting used at many places – NealGul

Instead of using Powermock:

## how to convert a static method into a non-static when it is referenced at many places in the codebase?

There are 3 easy, quick and safe steps:

1. create a non-static copy of that method (with a new name):

   ```
   class StaticMethodRefactoring {
       static int staticMethod(int b) {
           return b;
       }

       int nonStaticMethod(int b) {
           return b;
       }
   }
   ```
2. let the static version call the non-static version:

   ```
   class StaticMethodRefactoring {
       static int staticMethod(int b) {
           return new StaticMethodRefactoring(). nonStaticMethod(b);
       }

       int nonStaticMethod(int b) {
           return b;
       }
   }
   ```
3. use your IDE's *inline Method* refactoring to replace the static access with the non-static.

   Most likely there is an option to delete the old *static* version of the method. If some other projects use this static method you may which to keep it...

   Your IDE also provides the *inline method* feature at the place where you access the static method. This way you can change to non-static access step by step as needed.

That's it!

In all open projects in your current IDE session any access to the static method is replaced. Now you can change your *class under test* to get the instance injected via constructor or any other DI-mechanism and replace is for the tests with a simple *mockito*-mock...

Comment: not possible....i am not allowed to changed that method....seniors rejected my proposal

Comment: In that case: let them write their UnitTest Themselfs, It's part of their job anyway...

Comment: This method is been called in my class.and i am making Junit for my class and for that i need to mock this method......sorry if i am asking for too much

Comment: @NealGul *"This method is been called in my class.and i am making Junit for my class "* Then create a *wrapper object* that delegates to the static method. You might "reuse" this to wrap any other static method call in your program.

Comment: @NealGul *"sorry if i am asking for too much"* no excuses! we all need to ask to learn something...