# Power mockito verify static calls real method

Tags: java, junit, powermockito

I am trying to verify a static method was never called while testing a service method with powerMockito 1.6.4

I followed [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50255565/powermockito-verify-that-a-static-method-is-never-called#answer-50256270) to do the same.

following is my code.

```
@RunWith ( PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest ( MyClass.class)
@PowerMockIgnore ( "javax.net.ssl.*")
public class SomeTests
{
 @Test
    public void testMyMethodIsNotCalled() throws Exception
    {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class);
        underTest.testMethod();
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.never());
        MyClass.myMethod(Mockito.any());
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing now is that, `MyClass.myMethod(Mockito.any());`  calls the real `myMethod` and gives a nullPointerException.

My assumption is that `MyClass.myMethod(Mockito.any());` works with `PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.never());` in order to specify the static method to be verified.

Am I missing something?

Comment: you have to mock the behvaiour of the method MyClass.myMethod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to mock the static method behaviour also

i.e. something like this

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(NameOfClass.class);
expect( NameOfClass.nameOfMethod((URL)Mockito.any(),Mockito.anyString())).andReturn(actualOutput);
```

refer [Mock method with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44062928/mock-method-with-parameters)